# How to get a response from async fetch request? (node-tetch)

Tags: javascript, node.js, httprequest, node-fetch

I'm using `node-fetch` for a simple HTTP POST request but I'm unable to get a response from it?
I'm getting follwoing error:

```
(node:7200) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: FetchError: invalid json response
body at url reason: Unexpected token А in JSON at position 0
```

when this `console.log(res.json());` code runs. Fair, this URL returns a single line string as response. Maybe  `console.log(res.text());` should work for me?

Nope: `res.text() = [object Promise]`

How do I get response from this? My code:

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
var inspect = require('eyes').inspector({maxLength: false})
async function postLendingApplication(name) {
    try {
      console.log("Processing POST Loan.");
    
        var data = {
            "name" : name
        }
        var auth = Buffer.from("login:password").toString('base64')
        console.dir('data '+JSON.stringify(data));
        console.dir('auth '+auth);
      // the await eliminates the need for .then
      const res = await fetch("url.com", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': "Basic "+auth
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(data)
      })
     console.log("res.text() = "+res.text());
     //console.log(res.json());
      return res;
   }
   catch(err) { 

    throw err
    }
}

var result= postLendingApplication("00025003")
console.log(result)
```

Comment: `res.text()` returns a `Promise` just like `res.json()` will and you are logging it to the console without waiting for the `Promise` to settle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `await` keyword, text() is a promise.

```
const response = await res.text();
console.log(response);
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. But the last two lines I have: `var result = postLendingApplication("00025003")`
`console.log('la la la '+result)` return following: `la la la [object Promise]`  The whole reason for using this method is to get a response from an async HTTP request. And now it returns this?

Comment: Just use the await keyword when you call the function: var result = await postLendingApplication("00025003"). It is the same concept, you are assigning "result" the promise instead of waiting for the promise to resolve and then assigning the value that the promise resolves to.

Comment: Yeah I tried it but now I get `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`

Comment: I think you should read up on promises because there is some core understanding that I think you are missing (not a criticism, just a suggestion). Anyway, if you aren't calling this in an async function, just do the following: postLendingApplication("00025003").then((res) => { console.log(res); }). You will see the result logged. In short, the promise must be resolved at some point in order for you to get the result you are looking for.